# SQL to query JSON data

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table in question has a JSON column data like below,

```
{
   "CallerId": "TestId",
   "Product":[{"prop1":"value1", "ProductName":"TestName"},
              {"prop1":"value2", "ProductName":"TestName2"},
              {"prop1":"value3", "ProductName":"TestName3"}
             ]
}
```

I would like to check the ProductName property in the where filter of the query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share the RDBMS you are using (sql server, postgres, mysql, oracle, snowflake, teradata, mariadb, etc). Each platform has its own syntax for querying JSON

Comment: @JNevill I use MS SQL server.

Comment: Please do some research and have a go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`json_value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to query the `json` as well as [`CROSS APPLY OPENJSON()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to shred the `Product` array into individual rows for querying. This would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int, val nvarchar(max));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '{
   "CallerId": "TestId",
   "Product":[{"prop1":"value1", "ProductName":"TestName"},
              {"prop1":"value2", "ProductName":"TestName2"},
              {"prop1":"value3", "ProductName":"TestName3"}
             ]
}');

SELECT *
  FROM test
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(val,'$.Product') jsondt
  WHERE json_value(jsondt.value, '$.ProductName') Like '%Name2'
```

Which will return id `1`, the full json string, and the `{"prop1":"value2", "ProductName":"TestName2"}` bit that led to the successful match.

[example dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/8TLQgeDz)